# Creating Installer Package Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, installation

I have a C# application that requires .net version 4 in order to run.  I know how to create a basic installer using the Visual Stuido Installer Setup Project that comes with Visual Studio and that installs my application fine, however, I can't get it to check if .net version 4 is already installed in the client machine and if not install it.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Should I use a different approach besides this method? Purchasing a license for InstallShield is not an option as that is too expensive.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should follow [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN.  It should tell you what you need to know about creating an installer to check for .NET 4.

The long and short of it is, if you set it as a prerequisite, the installer will check that it is installed.

Comment: Hi @MyCodeSucks  After completing installation of window form MSI setup, my raw files(Design and coding) are also showing at installation location. I've developed this application using visual studio 2010. Setup created successfully, but after installation that MSI this problem is happening. Please help me. Thanks in advance.